# how to ad a location(not GPS) to view 'who's online'

Tags: views, 8

the view 'who's online' Shows the user names of the most recently active users, and the total number of active users. I want to add a location to this view.
Not a geolocation, geocoder but a UNIT of the company

example
Every shift 8 to 10 co workers choose 12 units beforehand. I want to display in which unit my co workers are, when online. The location is not able with GPS, because lack of signal.
I tried to made a contenttype with the 100 units. Every shift co workers have to choose 12 units beforehand.

I'm looking for the best way to add a field_unit to the view 'who's online'. 
when using geolocation, geocoder or adressfield is to complicated

co worker has to choose simple 'im here, sector unit 1' 'im here, sector unit 2' 'im here, sector unit 3' ect

The location is not able with GPS, because lack of signal.

What is the most simple solution to display and log this
I looked for modules that schedule, also looked the webform module. But im looking for a more simple solution

When possible I like to add 'previous unit' and 'next unit'.

Is there a module for this? I have looked for schedule modules and tried webform, but was to complex

workflow:
- I create a contenttype UNITS, with 1 text formatted field `field_unit`
- I create content (every unit is a single content)
- I create a field `field_unit`

now i can't add the field to the view 'who's online'?

how to solve this